# DB Table Concurrency Issue in Microservices

Tags: database, concurrency, microservices, isolation-level, distributed-transactions

How to handle concurrency-related issues on a DB table if multiple applications are reading and writing on it? This case may not be specific to microservices.

| OPERATION | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| GET_ORDER | COMPLETE |
| CALCULATE_PRICE | RUNNING |

A very basic use-case: multiple applications are writing in the above table. Before writing, they check if same operation is already present in RUNNING status. If not present, they insert the entry. Otherwise they just skip. Both read and write operations are simple SQL queries.

Problem is - 2 different applications can read at the same time and find that there is no 'CREATE_INVOICE' operation RUNNING, so they both will insert it in the table which will now look like:

| OPERATION | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| GET_ORDER | COMPLETE |
| CALCULATE_PRICE | RUNNING |
| CREATE_INVOICE | RUNNING |
| CREATE_INVOICE | RUNNING |

As a result the table has two duplicate CREATE_INVOICE records. Besides applying unique constraint on the table, what are the ways to resolve this?

Comment: You need to introduce a version (integer) column in your tables. Update the version for any change to the row. You use the version to determine if the row has changed since the last read. Read up on optimistic and pessimistic locking for details.

Answer (score 0):

By "2 different applications" do you mean that there are two completely separate applications which create invoices, or just 2 instances of the same application?

If the former, I'd be curious why there are two applications doing the same thing writing to the same DB.

If the latter, those instances will need to coordinate in some way (a uniqueness constraint on the table is an example of such coordination), and it's important to note that this coordination makes the application a little more stateful.

My preferred way of dealing with this would be to be event driven (e.g. by tapping into database change data capture) and sharding: for instance, when a `GET_ORDER` record is marked `COMPLETE` in the DB (resulting in a CDC record being published), based on the order ID, that CDC record is always routed to the same shard in the invoice creation application (or the price calculation application for that matter; your second table seems to imply that invoice creation can be simultaneous with price calculation), thus avoiding the conflict.